# How to create a VBA user interface to create charts based on different KPIs

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to this forum and VBA, and looking for creating a VBA user interface based on this data base:

[image: DataBase]

That allows the user to do the followings:

1. Pick a client name from a check box list that has all customer names (that are included in Column B. The user can select one client or more.

2- Create a chart from the data for that client.

Here's what the result should look like:

[How the chart should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkrlh.png)

except that using pivot table/chart edits the original data  (it sums it or does other operations on it) while I want to simply display the data as it is for  each of these clients separately so I can compare them.

Any help, links, directions would be most welcome,
Thank you!

PS: I have developed that data base so far based on files that the user selects, once I have the data, I do calculations and finally put the results in a data base. If you are interested in knowing how I created the Data base I can help you out.

Comment: I doubt you'd find anything that gives you exactly what you need. Try breaking the question down into _much_ smaller chunks, having a read of [MCVE], recording some macros....

Comment: Thank you Darren, you are absolutely right. It is complicated I will edit it.

Comment: Done! I feel that this makes more sense now!

Comment: Is your question about how to create a UI or how to process the data in VBA? It is not clear to me at all. Also please include what code you have that pertains to the specifics of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just put it all on a pivot table?. Failing that you could set up dedicated lists using named references. i.e when you select "Client1" in "Clients" the remaining details are returned.

The overall description of what you want to get out of it needs some elaboration.

Comment: Hello @Rossco, Thanks you for you feedback!  I have added a new picture to the original post (it didn't let me add the picture here) that depicts what I exactly one using pivot charts (inspired by your answer). In that picture, the user has a drop down list  of clients, he can select one or many,  in the X axis he has the date, and on the Y axis they have cost..., the only issue with pivot table/chart is that they sum the data for these clients while I just want to simply reflect the data without editing it ( no sum, multiplication...)

Answer (score 0):

If you right click the value you want to count (in the cell not the chart values box) and not sum you can change the value in the "summarise values by" field. If I have misunderstood let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an example so you can connect it with your data.

```
Sub setConnection()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim Pc As PivotCache
    Dim Pv As PivotTable
    Dim pFD As PivotField
    Dim con As WorkbookConnection
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim Cht As Chart, shp As Shape
    Dim objCht As ChartObject

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    myPath = WB.Path & "\" & "pivotData.xlsx" '<~~ set your data file path


    strConn = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=" & myPath & ";Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;';Jet OLEDB:System database='';Jet OLEDB:Registry Path='';Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=35;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password='';Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False"
    Set con = WB.Connections.Add( _
                Name:="Movie conn", _
                Description:="", _
                ConnectionString:=strConn, _
                CommandText:="Data$", _
                lCmdtype:=XlCmdType.xlCmdTable)
    'CommandText:="Data$" <~~ Database table name , this is Excel sheet 
    Set ws = Sheets("External") '<~~ set your sheet
    Set Target = ws.Range("a1")

    Target.CurrentRegion.Clear

    For Each objCht In ws.ChartObjects
        objCht.Delete
    Next objCht

    Set Pc = WB.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:=con)
    Set Pv = Pc.CreatePivotTable(Target, TableName:="pv3")

    Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddChart
    Set Cht = shp.Chart
    With Cht
        .SetSourceData Target.CurrentRegion
    End With

    Set pFD = Pv.PivotFields("Studio") 'set your field
    With pFD
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    Set pFD = Pv.PivotFields("Year")
    With pFD
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    Set pFD = Pv.PivotFields("Worldwide")
    With pFD
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlSum
        .Position = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Image

[image]